# Qt Creator : QtGui include error

Tags: qt

I wanted to learn Qt and so downloaded Qt library(5.0) and Qt creator for windows. There, I was not able to access QNetworkAccessManager..it gave an error when I included QNetworkAccessManager
I wasn't able to figure out the reason of the error and I was dual-booting with Ubuntu. So I downloaded Qt for Ubuntu and started using it, but, this time it is giving an error when I am including QtGui.
The errors are:

```
/home/shaarad/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:60:
  In file included from ../../../Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:60:0,
/home/shaarad/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/QtGui:33:
  from ../../../Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/QtGui:33,
/home/shaarad/Documents/JIGS/JIGS-FILE-SHARING-master/MainFrame.cpp:5:
  from ../JIGS-FILE-SHARING-master/MainFrame.cpp:5:
/home/shaarad/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qopengl.h:98: 
  error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
```

Any workaround will be helpful, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It's better to download the whole SDK from here : http://origin.releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.0/

Comment: To use qnetworkaccessmanager, add QT += network to your .pro file.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Those two provided the solution.

Comment: or one-liner: `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev -y`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the OpenGL include files. Install the `mesa-common-dev` package:

```
# apt-get install mesa-common-dev
```

This includes the `/usr/include/GL` directory.

Comment: Thanks! I did, but now it gives two errors, cannot find -lGL, and collect2:ld returned 1 exit status.. please help..thanks again... :)

Answer (score 2):

Install also:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing `qt5-default`:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora, you'll require:

```
sudo dnf install mesa-libGL-devel
```

Comment: some more explanation buddy?

Comment: On Fedora, this is what you'll need to install to get the OpenGL gl.h include - the other packages posted by others are not recognised on Fedora.